# How to highlight subset of values in scatter plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I want to highlight a subset of values in a scatter ggplot. However I get an error message and I dont know how to fix it (I am new in computational analysis) Here is the command:

```
ggplot(table, aes(x=soma_1.5.2.5h, y=PGC_1.5.2.5h)) +
  geom_point(shape=1, color = "gray") +
  geom_point(data = subset(table, high == TRUE), 
                    aes(x=table$soma_1.5.2.5h, y=PGC_1.5.2.5h, size = 2, color = "orange"))
```

So I want to highlight dots that are "TRUE" for high. 
I got:

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (108): x,
>   y, size, colour.

108 is the number of values that are TRUE for high.
Thanks a for your help

Comment: Try this: `geom_point(data = subset(table, high == TRUE), 
                    aes(x=table$soma_1.5.2.5h, y=PGC_1.5.2.5h), size = 2, color = "orange")`

Comment: You wrote `x=table$soma_1.5.2.5h` in your second (subsetted) `aes`. Try simply `x=soma_1.5.2.5h` instead. `table` still refers to the full (original) data frame. You want to refer to the subsetted data frame.

Comment: As a general rule, _don't use `$` inside `aes`_.

Comment: You could replace the second term with `geom_point(aes(shape=high,color=high))` and delete the last term.  Add some `scale_shape` and `scale_color` terms to customise the shapes and colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. Also thanks for your advices